# making the profile photo upload popup ONLY AFTER varifying the form

Tags: javascript, html

In my form, i have done the varification of the password and it works properly, then i added a pop up profile photo upload which is meant to popup ONLY AFTER the form has been varified, but this doesnt happen, it just pops up even if the two passwords arent the same.

this is the html code

```
   <p class="smedia"> <a href="" class="fb sign">Sign up with Facebook</a> <a href="" class="google plus">Sign up with Google+</a> </p>

        <p class="or">  OR  </p>

        <label for="name"> Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" required="required" />
        <label for="mail"> Email </label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" required="required" placeholder="mymail@example.com" />

        <label for="password"> Password</label>
        <input type="password" minlength="6" id="password" name="password" required="required" />
        <label for="compare_password">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" minlength="6" id="compare_password" name="compare_password" compareTo="password" required="required" />


        <p class="terms">By creating your account you agree to our <a href="#msa-popup">Rules</a> of use.</p>

        <button class='open-modal' data-modal="#modal1" type="submit">Create your account</button>

        <p class="corp"> <a href="signin.html">Sign in if you already have an account</a></p>
      </form>

      <!-- pop up -->
              <div class='modal' id='modal1'>
              <div class='content'>
              <h1 class='title'>Profile photo upload</h1>
              <div class="wrapper">
              <button class="no-image" id="img-result">Upload Image</button>
              </div>
              </div>
              <a class='btn submit' data-modal="#modal1" href="index.html">Submit</a>
              </div>
              </div>
```

The javascript code for the confirm password and popup

```
    /******************************
    pop up modal
    ******************************/
    $(".modal").each( function(){
        $(this).wrap('<div class="overlay"></div>')
    });

    $(".open-modal").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation;

        var $this = $(this),
                modal = $($this).data("modal");

        $(modal).parents(".overlay").addClass("open");
        setTimeout( function(){
            $(modal).addClass("open");
        }, 350);

        $(document).on('click', function(e){
            var target = $(e.target);

            if ($(target).hasClass("overlay")){
                $(target).find(".modal").each( function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("open");
                });
                setTimeout( function(){
                    $(target).removeClass("open");
                }, 350);
            }

        });

    });

    $(".close-modal").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation;

        var $this = $(this),
                modal = $($this).data("modal");

        $(modal).removeClass("open");
        setTimeout( function(){
            $(modal).parents(".overlay").removeClass("open");
        }, 350);

    });

    /******************************
    ending of pop up modal
    ******************************/

    /**************************************
    ***************************************
    ***************************************
    comparing the two passwords
    ***************************************
    ***************************************
    **************************************/

    (function() {
      'use strict';

      function comparePasswords(password, comparate, invalidmsg) {
        if (password.value !== comparate.value) {
          password.setCustomValidity(invalidmsg);
        } else {
          password.setCustomValidity('');
        }
      }

      var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[compareTo], input[data-compareTo]');

      for (var i = 0, input; input = inputs[i]; i++) {
        var form = input.form;
        var comparateName = input.getAttribute('compareTo') || input.getAttribute('data-compareTo');
        var comparates = form.querySelectorAll('[name="' + comparateName + '"]');

        if (comparates.length === 0) {
          console.error('CompareTo could not find an element with the name "' + comparateName + '". Please ensure that one element with that name exists.');
          continue;
        }

        if (comparates.length > 1) {
          console.error('CompareTo found more than one (' + comparates.length + ') elements with the name "' + comparateName + '". Please ensure that only one element with that name exists.')
          continue;
        }

        var comparate = comparates[0];
        var error = input.getAttribute('compareToError') ||
          input.getAttribute('data-compareToError') ||
          'These passwords don\'t match.';

        var callback = (function(input, comparate, invalidmsg) {
          return function() {
            comparePasswords(input, comparate, invalidmsg);
          }
        })(input, comparate, error);

        input.addEventListener('change', callback);
        comparate.addEventListener('change', callback);
      }
    }());

    /**************************************
    ***************************************
    comparing two passwords ending
    ***************************************
    **************************************/
```

Comment: name your validation function and make it rerun a boolean value indicating validity, then only open the modal if the value returned is true.

Comment: @thedude honestly i am not too good with javascript, i just learnt the basics, but i dont know how to use it. please can you help out. i got most of the javascript from codepen